# Transfer Data to another worksheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I have read through some of the other previous responses and got close to a solution, however I am stuck nonetheless. I am trying to take a data set from a single row in "Sheet2" and copy it over to the next empty row (cell) in "Data". Currently my VBA will correctly copy the data from "Sheet2" to "Data" and then it will select the next empty cell *after* the information is copied over. Selecting the next empty cell after the macro runs is what I need, but I also need it to select the first empty cell in "Data" *before* it copies the information over. Currently, it will copy the information into the cell that is selected which could be anywhere on "Data". This is what I currently have.

```
Sub Select_Next_Cell()
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Data").Select
On Error Resume Next
Dim xCell As Range
For Each xCell In ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Cells
If Len(xCell) = 0 Then
    xCell.Select
    Exit For
End If
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Next
End Sub
```

If someone could be as so kind as insert or alter my current formula to show me what I am missing, this would be extremely helpful. Thank you in advance!

I tried to copy and past the 'Select next empty cell' formula both before and after the copying and pasting data set, but this caused an error in my VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need select and copy --> read [How to avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23913882/16578424) and [How to avoid copy/paste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64611707/16578424).

You can use this code - which is split in a main routine and sub-routines. Like this code is easier to read and understand:

```vb
Public Sub copyDataFromSheet2ToSheetData()

Dim rgSource As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2")
    Set rgSource = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Rows(2).EntireRow)
End With

Dim rgTarget As Range
Set rgTarget = getFirstEmptyRow(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data"))

copyData rgSource, rgTarget

End Sub


Public Sub copyData(rgSource As Range, rgTarget As Range)
With rgSource
    rgTarget.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
End With
End Sub

Public Function getFirstEmptyRow(ws As Worksheet) As Range
With ws
    Set getFirstEmptyRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End With
End Function
```

By using `UsedRange` you can omit the the selection-part from your first part of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding using `Select`, `Selection` and `ActiveSheet` and use fully qualified objects instead.

See comments inside code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Select_Next_Cell()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Sht2 As Worksheet, DataSht As Worksheet

' set the worksheet objects
Set Sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set DataSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

' get last row with data in "Data" worksheet (column A)
LastRow = DataSht.Cells(DataSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Sht2.Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Copy
DataSht.Range("A" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```